# GetField returning null

Tags: c#, .net

i'm trying to getField but is always returning null
Here's a image of the code and the watchs of the variables.

Code: `FieldInfo xSortField = xFieldInfo.GetValue(x).GetType().GetField(this.prefixedSortBy[i]);`

[image]

Comment: Try adding binding flag instance to the GetField call: `GetField(this.prefixedSortBy[i], BindingFlags.Instance)`

Comment: You're trying to get field `ssId` on an `Int32`?  That doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to look more closely at what you're doing, as it doesn't seem to make much sense.

`xFieldInfo.GetValue(x)` returns a boxed integer `2`. `GetType()` then returns `typeof(int)`

You're then trying to get the `FieldInfo` for the field `ssId` on `int`.  That doesn't exist.

It looks like you intended this:

```
FieldInfo xSortField = x.GetType().GetField(this.prefixedSortBy[i])
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to use BindingFlags

```
GetField("FieldName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Answer (score 7):

You must specify either `BindingFlags.Instance` or `BindingFlags.Static` as a second argument in order to get a return value.

Also `BindingFlags.NonPublic` should be used to get non-public fields.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4ek9c21e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answers there is a clear distinction between Fields and Properties. Trying to get a property but using GetField() will result in null.

To get property Info:

`var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName);`

to get value of field/property you can use a method like this:

```
public static T? GetFieldValue<T>(object obj, string fieldName)
        where T : struct
    {
        var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName);
        if (property != null)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(T))
            {
                return (T)property.GetValue(obj);
            }

            return null;
        }

        var field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName);
        if (field != null && field.FieldType == typeof(T))
        {
            return (T)field.GetValue(obj);
        }

        return null;
    }
```